# Conditions for taking a limit into an infinite sum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $f\left(x\right)={\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g_{n}\left(x\right)}$ under what conditions is it true that: $$\lim_{x\to c}f\left(x\right)={\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lim_{x\to c}g_{n}\left(x\right)}
$$

I know it's true if ${\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g_{n}\left(x\right)}$ converges uniformly, are there weaker sufficient conditions?

**Small addition to the question:**

Specifically given $\alpha>0$ the power series of $f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{\alpha}}$ is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha\left(\alpha+1\right)\left(\alpha+2\right)\cdots\left(\alpha+\left(n-1\right)\right)}{n!}x^{n}$$
It converges uniformly in $\left(-1,1\right)$ and of course we know that ${\displaystyle \lim_{x\to1^{-}}\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{\alpha}}}$. I want to use that to say that: $$\infty=\lim_{x\to1^{-}}\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{\alpha}}={\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha\left(\alpha+1\right)\left(\alpha+2\right)\cdots\left(\alpha+\left(n-1\right)\alpha\right)}{n!}\lim_{x\to1^{-}}x^{n}}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha\left(\alpha+1\right)\left(\alpha+2\right)\cdots\left(\alpha+\left(n-1\right)\right)}{n!}$$

What justification do I use here? I can't use uniform convergence since the power series does not converge at $x=1$.

Thanks!

Comment: [Abel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_theorem) is one example.

Comment: Abel's theorem is specific to power series though.

Comment: About your edit: if the series converged, you could apply Abel's theorem and deduce that $\lim 1/(1-x)^\alpha<\infty$. So you see, you did not want my Abel's theorem example and that was what you needed...What a coincidence!

Comment: However, in that case, a simple monotone convergence theorem suffices.

Comment: @Julien the original question was for general curiosity. The addition came a bit afterwards :)
Still pretty nice coincidence Abel's test did provide the answer in an alternate fashion. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Yes, that's a good question. Note that Dimitris Dallas's answer actually mentions a stronger, not weaker, assumpotion. That's Weierstrass M-test, and this corresponds to normal convergence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to regard the sum as the integral of $g_n(x)$ with respect to the counting measure:$$\int_\mathbb Ng_n(x){d\mu(n)}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty g_n(x)$$
If $g_n(x)$ is dominated by an integrable function $f_n$, i.e. $$|g_n(x)|\leq f_n,\forall n\in\mathbb N,\forall x\text{ and }\int_\mathbb Nf_nd\mu(n)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n<\infty$$
Then you can use **Dominated Convergence** theorem and switch limits and integration

Comment: You miss some sum signs.

Comment: Also, what you are describing is actually Weierstrass M-test. Which implies uniform convergence.

Comment: You are right about M-test! I just figured this out!

Comment: Don't you need that all the $g_n$ have to be dominated by one single $f$?